# Fade image from black in UIImageView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiimageview

I'm using the `SDWebImage` framework to load an image from the web asynchronously, and I'm trying to get fading to work. I have it currently fading from white to the image, as such (long animation speed for testing):

```
self.pictureImageView.alpha = 0.0f;
        [UIView transitionWithView:nil
                          duration:5.0f
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                        animations:^{
                            [self loadImage:urlForPic];
                            self.pictureImageView.alpha = 1.0f;
                        } completion:nil];
```

In `loadImage:` I just do this:

```
if(urlForPic)
        [self.pictureImageView setImageWithURL:urlForPic
                              placeholderImage:nil];
```

In my storyboard, I have the background of the `UIImageView` set to black, and its `alpha` to 1.0 and `opaque` checked. If I don't load any image, when loading my view controller it shows up with a black background, as intended. However, as soon as I set an image and do the animation, it fades from white to the image, which I don't want.

Is there a way to have it fade from black to the image with a cross dissolve animation?

Comment: The bg color of the image view doesn't matter (unless the image has any transparency). The white you see is from whatever is behind the image view. Change that to black.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the view (or container view) background color of black, the animation would look like a fade from black.

Comment: No problem. Glad to have helped.